# Entering UK with Article 10 Residency Card

Tags: united-kingdom, eu-spouses

I am curious as to whether or not my partner's Article 10 Residency card (issued in the Czech Republic where we both live) will be sufficient for him to visit the UK with me without requiring a visa.

We're both living and working in Prague, I'm a UK citizen and he's from Belarus (so he's currently able to be resident and working here as the family member of an EU citizen). I'm only curious about it allowing him to visit the UK, we have no plans to relocate, but Belarusians need a tourist visa for the UK and he's previously had to pay quite a lot.

I'm not interested in the Surinder Singh method as we aren't married. Will this fact also prevent him from entering with the Article 10 card? We had to present extensive evidence of our relationship to the Czech authorities to get the card, have police visit our home, etc, but marriage is not a requirement here to qualify as a family member.

I know it's recommended you bring evidence of your relationship, but obviously we've no marriage certificate. I know that in theory he should now be able to enter without getting an additional visa, but I'm worried that we'll be prevented as we're not married.

Edit: The only official recognition of our relationship would be via the Czech immigration services when they granted the EU family member residence permit. This was done by providing evidence like our lease, bank statements showing transfers between us, photographs, and tickets and hotel bookings for shared trips.

Comment: A UK citizen claiming freedom of movement for a family member is invoking Surinder Singh regardless of the relationship with the family member.

Comment: To answer your question it is probably necessary to know whether your partnership has been officially registered with any civil authority or if you are instead "partners in a durable relationship, duly attested."